# I met an error syntax when testing SQL injection with login page

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

When I try to test how SQL injection works in my login page and my code is:

```sql
public function login() {
      
        $db = new Database();
    
 
//---------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------
        $p = $this->getPhone();
        $pa = $this->getPassword();
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       
    // $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Account WHERE phone = ? and password = ?";
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Account WHERE phone = $p and password = $pa";
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Use an array to pass parameters in the correct order
        // $params = array($this->phone, $this->password);
        // var_dump($sql); 
 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       
 
        // $result = $db->query($sql,$params);
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $result = $db->query($sql);
    //    var_dump($result);
     
            if ($result) {
                // Check if there is a matching user
                if ($result > 0) {
                    return true;

It
                    
                } else {
                    // Incorrect phone or password
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Error in the query
                // You might want to log the error or handle it appropriately
                return false;
            }
        
       
    }
```

So i met this ERROR when run by PHP with XAMPP:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '&'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '&'. ) )

How can i fix this?

I tried to fix it but this wasn't working

Comment: *Why* are you injecting your parameters? I *hope* your column `password` isn't storing plain text passwords (which is appears to be). These are all *terrible* security flaws for you and your users. **Parametrise** your queries. Salt and Hash your passwords.

Comment: Go and rewrite this to use _prepared statements_, instead of inserting data values directly into the SQL.

Comment: `phone = $p and password = $pa` - `strings` within the sql need to be within quotes and presumably `password` contains  a string?

Comment: As for the reason, your injected value isn't in quotes, so of course it fails. `password = MyPassword&123` for example, will generate an error as it's not valid syntax. Again, **parametrise**.

Comment: From what OP is saying *When I try to test how SQL injection works* it is an exercise in SQL Injection - so I would expect it to be written badly without prepared statements - that's the point

Comment: I think php has a function that allows printing variables, echo or something. You can use it to debug your queries to understand what could be the problem

Comment: `How can i fix this` use parameters in prepared statements, not string concatenation or interpolation (which is the same thing). Quoting won't help as someone could enter `' OR 1=1;-` or `' OR 1=1; DROP TABLE Users; --` as a password.